# what exactly does return $http.post mean in angular when creating a factory service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

So I have been trying to understand the meaning of: `return $http.post('/some link')` but I am unable to fully wrap my head around it.

Let's say I have a node/express backend, and am using angular for my frontend. One of the functions in my api is this:

```
 var api = express.Router();
 //other code

api.post('/login', function(req,res) {
        User.findOne({username:req.body.username})
            .select('password').exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return;
            } else {
                if (!user) {
                    res.json({message: 'user does not exist!'});
                } else {
                    var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                    if (!validPassword) {
                        res.json({message: 'invalid password!'});
                    } else {
                        var token = createToken(user);

                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            message: "successfully logged in",
                            token: token
                        });                    
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

I then create an angular factory service to get the data from the backend like this:

```
var authService = angular.module('authService', {});


authService.factory('Auth', function($http, $q) {  
    var authFactory = {};


    //authToken: factory which has methods to get and set token
    authFactory.login = function(username, password, authToken) {

        return $http.post('/login', {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })   
        .then(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
                return data;
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Generally,  POST method puts the data into the backend, it doesn't return anything, but since $http.post returns a promise object, it is this object that we are returning. In my case, this object is this:

```
 res.json({
                            success: true,
                            message: "successfully logged in",
                            token: token
                        });
```

my question is this: is my train of thought correct? I have been reading and re-reading the angular documentation on this, and although it offered some relief, I cant help but think I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.post` returns a promise. The `then` method can take up to 2 arguments, a `resolve` handler or a `rejection` handler. Each handler only take up one 1 parameter though. So in your example:

```
return $http.post('/login', {
      username: username,
      password: password
}).then(function(err, data){});
```

It's actually wrong. Your `resolve` handler should only take 1 argument (the `data` being received). If there's an error, you'd need to use the 2nd argument.

```
.then(function(data) { /*resolved*/ }, function(err) { /*something happened*/ });
```

Although it's much better if you use `catch`:

```
.then(function(data) { /*resolved*/ })
.catch(function(err) { /*something bad happened*/ });
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on the resolve handler, it makes sense. 

Regarding the promise, does it return the `res.json({...})` object?

Comment: I think you'll get JSON string but not a JS object. You'll need to specify `{responseType : 'json'}` on the third argument of `$http.post` if you want the JSON string to be parsed into a JS Object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying that! (: